# Custom Yeoman Generator can't overwrite files

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to create a simple generator to standardize creation of node projects. In my generator I make calls to copyTpl like:

```
generator.fs.copyTpl(
  sourcePath,
  destinationPath
  context,
  //ignore ES6 constructs in our templates
  {
    interpolate: /<%=([\s\S]+?)%>/g
  }
);
```

This works great as long as no files exist in my target directory. Unfortunately, if a file exists and I choose to overwrite it I get the following error:

```
Error: no writecb in Transform class
at afterTransform (/Users/gerrard00/projects/generator-mine/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:95:33)
at TransformState.afterTransform (/Users/gerrard00/projects/generator-mine/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:79:12)
at Object.callback (/Users/gerrard00/projects/generator-mine/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:787:7)
at /Users/gerrard00/projects/generator-mine/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/util/conflicter.js:79:18
at Conflicter.<anonymous> (/Users/gerrard00/projects/generator-mine/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/util/conflicter.js:193:12)
at PromptUI.onCompletion (/usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js:57:10)
at AnonymousObserver.Rx.AnonymousObserver.AnonymousObserver.completed (/usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:1550:12)
at AnonymousObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onCompleted (/usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:1489:14)
at Subject.Rx.Subject.addProperties.onCompleted (/usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:5871:19)
at Subject.tryCatcher (/usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:63:31)
```

This means that my generator only works in empty folders. I've re-read the "Creating a generator" docs about twenty times, but I can't figure out what I'm missing. What do I need to add to my generator to prevent this error?

Update: The files are actually overwritten, despite the error.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the issue was with the fact that my code was walking a directory asynchronously using the node-walk package. The calling method used the generator async method, but called the done callback synchronously. I modified it to call the done callback in the walk end event handler and the error went away.